# Apollo Link response headers

Tags: apollo-client

I am using the latest version of Apollo Client in a simple React app and I am trying to pull out a header value from the response that is being used to show the size of the record set being returned.

I appreciate that this is not the most elegant way of providing the result set size, but that is how the API has currently been set up.

I was hoping to use the the middleware type options to do this, but when I inspect the response object I can't seem to pull out any headers.

The network trace does show that the response header is as expected so I suspect I am misunderstanding how to get at the underlying objects that I need.

I have checked the documentation, but nothing stands out as obvious hence the question here ...

Answer (score 32):

When the backend responds, the headers should include:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *` // or the name of your refreshToken field

Here you have the full code:

Front-end: (Apollo & React)

```js
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: URL_SERVER_GRAPHQL })

// Setup the header for the request
const middlewareAuthLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)

  const authorizationHeader = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: authorizationHeader
    }
  })
  return forward(operation)
})
```

```js
// After the backend responds, we take the refreshToken from headers if it exists, and save it in the cookie.
const afterwareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return forward(operation).map(response => {
    const context = operation.getContext()
    const { response: { headers } } = context

    if (headers) {
      const refreshToken = headers.get('refreshToken')
      if (refreshToken) {
        localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, refreshToken)
      }
    }

    return response
  })
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([middlewareAuthLink, afterwareLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

In the backend (express).
If we need to refresh the token (e.g: because the actual one is going to expire)

```js
const refreshToken = getNewToken()
res.set({
  'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'refreshToken', // The frontEnd can read refreshToken
  refreshToken
})
```

Documentation from: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/network-layer/#afterware

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to take the header and put it in the response. Maybe in some kind of wrapper object?

Comment: nice. thank you. finally i found the root of all evil

Answer (score 22):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2514

Have to access it via the operation context ... interestingly the dev tools appears to show that the headers object is empty, but you can then pull named headers from it ...

```js
const afterwareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return forward(operation).map(response => {
    const context = operation.getContext();
    const { response: { headers } } = context;
    
    if (headers) {
      const yourHeader = headers.get('yourHeader');
    }
    
    return response;
  });
});
```

Comment: I am using the same code, and I still receive `null`: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2514#issuecomment-546547336 any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Does anybody know why the dev tool shows the headers object is empty??

Comment: @K-Sato yes, header are lazy loaded i.e. they are loaded only the first time you access them. Try calling `headers.lazyInit();` and they will magically appear

Comment: If using CORS, you'll need to add your headers to `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` returned by your server: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2514#issuecomment-488347144 Otherwise you just get things like content length and type.

Comment: This DID NOT WORK for me. I had to `forward(operation).subscribe({complete: () => { console.info(operation.getContext().response.headers); })`