# How to get response header from useQuery of Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client, response-headers

I haven't been able to find a way to do this at all. Does anyone know if this is supported? Thanks.

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: For troubleshooting of errors.

Comment: what kind exactly? for data related errors usually `error` property gives enough info ... you can get network errors, too... just explore this object

Comment: @xadm the backend sends a correlation id as a response header. I need to get my hands on it to correlate the error with other things happening in the backend.

Comment: you can reach `response` in error-link (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#network-errors)

Comment: @xadm I can get `response` but I still don't see headers.  `response` contains `data` and `errors`.  None of them has headers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479911/6124657 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ApolloClient's methods for making requests, and the React Hooks that use them, serve as an abstraction over how the data is actually fetched. It could come from a remote server over HTTP, from the cache, from directly executing the request against a schema, etc. As a result, they don't expose any information regarding how the data was fetched in the first place, including transport-specific information like HTTP headers.

If you need to access this information, the appropriate place to do so would be inside a Link that you'd prepend to your `HttpLink` -- either an existing one like a `ContextLink` or `ErrorLink`, or some custom Link you roll yourself. If you're doing this in an error-handling context, then `ErrorLink` would be your best bet, as suggested in the comments.

`HttpLink` injects the raw response from the server into the context object used by all Links (see [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/480df382cf7db486ae76c56ac2522134d77e36fa/packages/apollo-link-http/README.md#context)). Assuming you're using the default `fetch` API as the fetcher, this response will be a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object.

So you can do something like this:

```
const link = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  const { response } = operation.getContext();
  const { headers, status } = response;
  
  // do something with the headers
});
```

Comment: Is there anything special I need to do with ErrorLink?  When an error happens, the `error` object still doesn't contain headers,

Comment: Same here. operation.getContext() does not contain property response. I am trying to access response header but not able to.